# services in android

Tags: android, android-service

can anybody give example with service in android?

Thanks

Comment: An example of what? Have you read the documentation on Services?

Comment: Google is your friend, there are plenty of tutorials

Comment: Lets be nicer to the new comers! I think two downvotes drive the point home quite well, over doing them just makes the user really scared and drives him away... =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android you basically have 2 kinds of services.

1. Local Service
2. Remote Service

If you run local service then your application as well as your service will run on same ProcessID

If you run a remote service it runs as a different process you can communicate with your service using Android Interface Definition Language(AIDL)

You can find sample codes in API Demo which comes along with Android SDK as well as here

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html#implementing